# How to specify JUnit category in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

When running the JUnit tests from Eclipse, where should I specify the `@category` variable?

For example, when using Maven via command line, I can specify the JUnit to run the tests cases annotated by "com.abc.MyTests" like this.

```
mvn test -Dgroups="com.abc.MyTests"
```

It looks like in the ***Run Configurations***, I can define environment variables in the ***Environment*** tab or specify arguments in the ***Arguments*** tab. However neither worked... (Maybe I didn't configure correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run JUnit tests from Eclipse, you normally don't do this via maven, so providing `-Dgroups`-like command line options specific to maven will not work.

You could create a maven configuration in Eclipse and invoke that from Eclipse, but I assume that is not what you want.

I suffered from this problem myself, and ended up creating dedicated suite classes:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(com.abc.MyTests.class)
@SuiteClasses( { AllTests.class } )
public class MyTestSuite { }
```

This assumes there is another class `AllTests` summarizing the total set of test classes:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
  Test1.class,
  Test2.class, 
  ...
})
public class AllTests { }
```

You can then run `MyTestSuite` directly from Eclipse.

Not exactly ideal, since it requires maintaining the `AllTests` class, and an extra class for any category you want to test from Eclipse.